# problem in gamecenter

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am facing some problems, that is, In my application the gamecenter works fine , but when ever I run another application then the multiple player list not showing... when I click on the all month data (ie,. who is playing that game) it will give me only my info. not giving me the full detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Apple's [Game Kit Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameCenterOverview/GameCenterOverview.html):

> To help you test your application, Apple provides a sandbox environment for Game Center. This sandbox environment duplicates the live functionality of Game Center, but is separate from the live servers. The sandbox allows you to test your Game Center features without making your application visible to regular users.

When you log in to Game Center on the app you're developing, you're logged in to the sandboxed version of Game Center (for apps in development).  To log back in to the standard Game Center environment, log yourself out and log back in from a different (i.e. released as opposed to in-development) game.